# Python scope problem. creating nested dictionary in loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on a dictionary of spoken language X and I start with a txt file with this format:

```
HEADWORD1
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
HEADWORD2
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
```

I have python script like this:

```
x_dict = {}
with open('x_file.txt', 'r') as x:
    x = x.readlines()
    headword = None
    for line in x:
        if headword != None:
            ENGLISH = None
            SPANISH = None
            if len(line) > 0:
                if not line.startswith(' '):
                    line = line.strip()
                    headword = line
                    x_dict[headword] = {}
                else:
                    line = line.strip()
                    if line.startswith('e) '):
                        ENGLISH = line[3:]
                    if line.startswith('s) '):
                        SPANISH = line[3:]
            #x_dict[headword] = {}
#            x_dict[headword]['test'] = 'foobar'
            if ENGLISH:
                print(ENGLISH)
                x_dict[headword]['English'] = ENGLISH
            if SPANISH:
                print(SPANISH)
                x_dict[headword]['Spanish'] = SPANISH 
        else:
            if len(line) > 0:
                if not line.startswith(' '):
                    line = line.strip()
                    headword = line
                    x_dict[headword] = {}
print(x_dict)
```

I expect output like this:

```
{'HEADWORD1': {'English': 'english translation', 'Spanish': 'spanish translation'}, 'HEADWORD2': {'English': 'english translation', 'Spanish': 'spanish translation'}}
```

But instead, I get:

```
{'HEADWORD1': {}, 'HEADWORD2': {}}
```

The print statements after `if ENGLISH:` and `if SPANISH:` print the expected information, and the commented out line puts a 'test': 'foobar' in each headword key's value dict.

I suspect that there's some kind of issue with scope, but I can't figure out (a) what the issue is, and (b) how to make the code do what I want it to.

Any ideas?

EDIT: So, some of you pointed out that the indent was off and a couple colons were missing. It was an effect of trying to make remake the example with generic variable names. I fixed that with a couple other improvements. And indeed the example runs as it should. However, the *real* code still doesn't work. I've compared the two line by line, and I don't see the reason one works and the other doesn't. Here's that *real* code:

```
def main():

    karttunen_dict = {}

    with open('karttunen.txt', 'r') as karttunen:
        karttunen = karttunen.readlines()
        headword = None

        for line in karttunen:

            if headword != None:

                ENGLISH = None
                SPANISH = None
                GRAMMAR = None
                COMMENT = None
                SOURCE = None
                LEXREF = None

                if len(line) > 0:

                    if not line.startswith(' '):
                        line = line.strip()
                        line = line.lower()
                        headword = line
                        karttunen_dict[headword] = {}

                    else:
                        line = line.strip()
                        if line.startswith('e) '):
                            ENGLISH = line[3:]
                        elif line.startswith('g) '):
                            GRAMMAR = line[3:]
                        elif line.startswith('s) '):
                            SPANISH = line[3:]
                        elif line.startswith('a) '):
                            SOURCE = line[3:]
                        elif line.startswith('c) '):
                            COMMENT = line[3:]
                        elif line.startswith('r) '):
                            LEXREF = line[3:]
                        else:
                            print( '~~~~-?-?-?-~~~~', headword, '~~~~-?-?-?-~~~~', line.strip())

                #karttunen_dict[headword] = {}
    #            karttunen_dict[headword]['English'] = 'test'
                if ENGLISH:
                    print(ENGLISH)
                    karttunen_dict[headword]['English'] = ENGLISH
                if SPANISH:
                    karttunen_dict[headword]['Spanish'] = SPANISH
                if GRAMMAR:
                    karttunen_dict[headword]['Grammar'] = GRAMMAR
                if COMMENT:
                    karttunen_dict[headword]['Comment'] = COMMENT
                if SOURCE:
                    karttunen_dict[headword]['Source'] = SOURCE
                if LEXREF:
                    karttunen_dict[headword]['Lexical Reference'] = LEXREF
                        
            else:
                if len(line) > 0:
                    if not line.startswith(' '):
                        line = line.strip()
                        line = line.lower()
                        headword = line
                        karttunen_dict[headword] = {}

    print(karttunen_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

along with a sample from the source file:

```
CHĪCHĪLTICCIHUĀPAH-TLI

        e) a medicinal plant

        s) cierta planta medicinal (R)

        a) (1)Rp.73

        c) The literal sense of this is "red female-medicine".

        r) see CHĪCHĪLTIC, CIHUĀPAH-TLI



CHĪCHĪLTICCUAHU(I)-TL

        e) candlewood, a spiny red-flowering bush (Fouquieriasplendens, Fouquieria formosa)
        s) ocotillo (Z)

        a) (2)Zp.90,151

        r) see CHĪCHĪLTIC, CUAHU(I)-TL



CHĪCHĪLTZAPO-TL

        e) mamey (a type of fruit)

        s) zapote colorado, mamey (Z)

        a) (3)Zp.80,131,151

        c) In all three attestations Z fails to mark the vowelof the first syllable long.
        r) see CHĪCHĪLTIC, TZAPO-TL



CHĪCHĪMĒCAPAH-TLI

        e) a potent medicinal plant

        s) planta medicinal muy ceŸlebre, pero demasiadamenteactiva (R)
        a) (1)Rp.73

        c) R does not mark the vowels of the first threesyllables long.  An alternative analysis is acompound of CHICHI "dog", MECA-TL "vine", PAH-TLI"medicine".
        r) see CHĪCHĪMĒCA-TL, PAH-TLI
```

and the output when I run the code

```
a medicinal plant
candlewood, a spiny red-flowering bush (Fouquieriasplendens, Fouquieria formosa)
mamey (a type of fruit)
a potent medicinal plant
{'chīchīlticcihuāpah-tli': {}, '': {}, 'chīchīlticcuahu(i)-tl': {}, 'chīchīltzapo-tl': {}, 'chīchīmēcapah-tli': {}}
```

Comment: Don't do `x = x.readlines()`. Files are already iterable

Comment: You need to fix your indentation to accurately reflect what you are actually running, what you provided raises a SyntaxError due to the indentation

Comment: Also, *everything here is in the same scope* so I'm fairly sure scope isn't the problem, but again, you have to give us a [mcve]

Comment: I am getting `{'HEADWORD1': {'Spanish': 'panish translation'}, 'HEADWORD2': {'Spanish': 'panish translation'}}`, which is what I would expect from tracing through the code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist so am I, if I fix the indentation and add colons to `if not line.startswith(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

So stupid. It was the blank lines. I don't really understand why atm, but it was the blank lines.

I `rstrip()`ed the list after `readlines()` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As some have pointed out, I'm not entirely sure what the end goal is. However, I believe that this will provide the end result that you're looking to achieve (assuming that the text file is formatted as described in the original post).

```
import re

data = {}

english = r'e\)\s.*'
spanish = r's\)\s.*'

with open ('translations.txt', 'r') as text:
    text_info = text.readlines()
    text_length = len(text_info)

    values = ['headline', 'english', 'spanish']
    
    for i in range(0, text_length, 3):
        values[0] = text_info[i]
        values[1] = text_info[i + 1]
        values[2] = text_info[i + 2]
    
        data[values[0].replace('\n', '')] = {'English': \
                           re.search(english, values[1]).group()\
                           .replace('e) ', ''), \
                           'Spanish': \
                           re.search(spanish, values[2]).group()\
                           .replace('s) ', '')}
   
text.close()
```

I tested with the following text file input.

```
HEADWORD1
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
HEADWORD2
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
HEADWORD3
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
HEADWORD4
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
HEADWORD5
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
HEADWORD6
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
HEADWORD7
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
HEADWORD8
    e) english translation
    s) spanish translation
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution and I have used similar code in other projects. However, in this case, it won't work because there are 6 possible "fields" (english, spanish, etc), but not all headwords have all 6 fields. In fact *most* don't have all 6. (see the edit to my original post). I gave a too neat rendition of the data in the minimal example.